# Github rebase & merge VS Git rebase & merge

Tags: git, github, merge, gitlab, rebase

I saw on the GitHub's docs [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-merge-methods-on-github) that the GitHub merge & rebase behaviour differs slightly from the `git rebase` because the rebase and merge on GitHub will always update the committer information and create new commit SHAs, whereas git rebase outside of GitHub does not change the committer information when the rebase happens on top of an ancestor commit.

So can anyone explain me the mechanism behind this? which information about the commiter is changed?

Thank you

Comment: Committer will always be whomever is running the operation... at least in plain git... the author will remain the same. (unless you trick it with environment variables and stuff, of course).

Answer (score 7):

A regular `git rebase`, done locally on your own computer, tries hard to optimize things a bit.  A GitHub rebase, done remotely in GitHub's computer, tries hard to make sure nothing gets optimized.

A concrete example is, I think, helpful here.  Suppose we have these commits locally:

```
          I--J--K   <-- feature (HEAD)
         /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

If you run `git rebase main`, while on `feature` like this, your Git *must* copy commit `I` to a new commit `I'`.  The difference between the original `I` commit, and the new `I'` commit, is that `I'` probably contains a different *snapshot* (set of all files), and that `I'` *definitely* has a different *parent*.  The parent commit of `I'` is `H` (vs `G` for `I`).  The snapshot is different if the snapshot in `H` differs from that in `G`, since the point of a rebase is to turn the `G`-vs-`I` *changes* into the same *changes* in `H`-vs-`I'`:

```
          I--J--K   [abandoned]
         /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
            \
             I'-J'-K'  <-- feature (HEAD)
```

Similar rules apply to `J'`-vs-`J` and `K'`-vs-`K`.  The new and improved commits *are* different; they *have to be* different.

But, if you have *this:*

```
             I--J--K   <-- feature (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

and you run `git rebase main`, your Git can look at the relative positions of `H` and `I` and say to itself: *Hey... if I copy `I` to a new `I'`, whose parent is `H`, the result is going to match `I`.  The diff I get from `H` to `I`, and the diff I would get from `H` to a new copy `I'`, would be **the same**.  The parent would be **the same**.  So ... why bother copying at all?  Let me just **re-use** the existing `I`.*

Your Git will repeat this reasoning for `J` and `K` as well.  So when the rebase finishes, you will have this in your repository:

```
             I--J--K   <-- feature (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

Literally nothing has changed.  The actual hash IDs of the three commits are identical; the committers are identical; everything is bit-for-bit identical, and the commit hash IDs still match up.

You can, however, *force* Git to *copy* the commits anyway, putting in new committer timestamps.  If you force your Git to do this you'll end up with:

```
             I--J--K   [abandoned]
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
            \
             I'-J'-K'  <-- feature (HEAD)
```

where the three new commits have the same snapshots, but different timestamps in the committer lines and hence different hash IDs from the original three commits.

To force a local rebase like this, you can use `git rebase -f`; this works with or without `-i`.  If you *don't* use the `-f` or `--force` option here, though, when and whether your Git actually manages to do this optimization locally depends on your particular Git version.  So not every rebase gets optimized like this.  But it's common enough, and for some particular purposes,<sup>1</sup> the force-new-commits option has been around for quite a long time now.

When you use the GitHub rebase-and-merge option, GitHub effectively turns on the force option.  Whether that's literally the case, or just a side effect of the way GitHub implemented their rebase code—they had to modify Git a bit to make some of their special sharing magic with forks work better, for instance, and this may play a role here; and they use bare repositories, where rebase is normally impossible anyway—I have no idea.  But they wind up doing the copying every time.  This produces new `committer` information in each commit, which means the new commits have new, unique hash IDs that do not match the originals.

(This is actually rather annoying when working in a corporate environment.  At least, I found it so.  It happens even without using a fork, so the bare-repo thing is probably the real culprit.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The main use of a forced-copy-rebase, at least as far as I know, is to re-do a merge that got reverted.  Suppose we have this:

```
             I--J--K   <-- feature
            /       \
...--F--G--H------L--M--W   <-- main
```

where `feature` got merged into `main` but then someone found that there was a bug, so commit `M` was reverted using commit `W` (M upside down, stolen from Linus).  The bug is then fixed:

```
             I--J--K--N   <-- feature
            /       \
...--F--G--H------L--M--W   <-- main
```

but if we now merge `feature` into `main` as is, we'll get merge conflicts and/or not get any of the effects from commits `I-J-K`, because revert `W` undoes what they do.  This happens because Git uses the hash IDs to know what's going on.

Suppose, then, that we *trick* Git into *copying* `I-J-K` in place even though it's "unnecessary":

```
             I--J--K
            /       \
...--F--G--H------L--M--W   <-- main
            \
             I'--J'--K'--N   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

We can now `git switch main && git merge feature`:

```
             I--J--K
            /       \
...--F--G--H------L--M--W--M2   <-- main (HEAD)
            \             /
             I'--J'--K'--N   <-- feature
```

where `M2` has a snapshot that is basically `M`-plus-the-bug-fix-in-`N`.

There are of course other ways to get the desired result, but this is [the one Linus outlined so many years ago](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt).